# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined - Processing.js

Tags: processing.js

I keep getting this error, and I have no clue what is wrong. I checked all variables, but all of them are defined at least somewhere

```
int creatures = 5;
int deathChance = 5;
int repChance = 10;

int timer = 0;

int rand = 0;
int CurrentCreatures = 0;
int b = 0;

void draw(); {
    if(timer < 100)
    {
        b = 0;
        CurrentCreatures = creatures;
        while(b < CurrentCreatures)
        {
            rand = random(0,100);
            if(rand <= repChance)
            {
                creatures += 1;
            }

            rand = random(0,100);
            if(rand <= deathChance)
            {
                creatures -= 1;
            }
            b += 1;
        }
        println(creatures);
        timer += 1;
    }
}
```

what the program should be doing is printing the value of creatures over 100 generations (yes this is my attempt at some "life" simulator.

Comment: Don't use processing.js - it was discontinued in December of 2018, over a year ago. If you're writing new code, please use https://p5js.org. And on a programming note, using the same conventions as everyone else is important to make sure people don't get confused by your code: varables use camelCase with a starting lowercase (so no `CurrentCreatures`, instead use `currentCreatures`), class names use CamelCase with starting uppercase, constants/final use all-caps with underscores to separate name parts. Finally: put this code in the Processing IDE, and it'll immediately tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here: `void Draw(); {` the `;` is an end of instruction character

So it is trying to execute a function called draw, the it tries to do everything inside the `{`'s

possibly something like:

```
function draw() {
    if(timer < 100) {
        b = 0;
        CurrentCreatures = creatures;

        while(b < CurrentCreatures) {
            rand = random(0,100);

            if(rand <= repChance) {
                creatures += 1;
            }

            rand = random(0,100);

            if(rand <= deathChance) {
                creatures -= 1;
            }

            b += 1;
        }

        println(creatures);
        timer +=1;
    }
}
```